# html код с блоками

Tags: javascript, html5

У меня есть html код с блоками
Как наложить друг на друга их и написать на js чтобы они поочередно появлялись

```css
.images {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.images>div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.im1 {
  background-color: #000;
}

.im2 {
  background-color: #333;
}

.im3 {
  background-color: #555;
}

.im4 {
  background-color: #777;
}

.im5 {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="im1"></div>
    <div class="im2"></div>
    <div class="im3"></div>
    <div class="im4"></div>
    <div class="im5"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(1000 * index).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.images {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.images>div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.im1 {
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
}

.im2 {
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 2;
}

.im3 {
  background-color: #555;
  z-index: 3;
}

.im4 {
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 4
}

.im5 {
  background-color: #999;
  z-index: 5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="img im1"></div>
    <div class="img im2"></div>
    <div class="img im3"></div>
    <div class="img im4"></div>
    <div class="img im5"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Исключительно исходя из требований можно, например, так.
**1000** - это скорость в миллисекундах, можно менять, тем самым меняя интервал между сменами.